# Optimal way to pass payload in Server Based Function using "use server" in Next js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have this function that returns an array of dummy data objects. Additionally, I have some sorting fields stored in the useContext, and their values are being stored in the store. If a payload is sent, I want to filter the data accordingly and return it when the Search button is clicked. So, where should I use those functions and mutate data?

Is it a good practice to use those functions inside here ?

```
"use server";

import { DATA } from "/constants/data";

interface IPAYLOAD {
  name: string;
  location: string[];
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date
}

export const getData = async (payload?: IPAYLOAD) => {
  return DATA;
};
```

Comment: if the whole data is already sent to the client, then you can sort/filters them in the client. but most of the time in a real project, the data is too large and we never send them all to the client at once. So we send the user's sort/filters to the backend and we sort/filter the data using the database which is already optimized for this and does this process really blazing fast.

Comment: if it's dummy data that lives in the client (_not fetched from server_), you don't need this file at all, a file starts with `use server` called [Server Action](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations#convention) and you totally don't need it here. it's mainly used to `POST` (_and `GET` as well_) data to your server. you can filter your data using`.filter()` or with any other array methods instantly in your component.